# How to get group object when the value of property is equal to itemSearch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, underscore.js, lodash

How to get group {object} when one property with [array] value is itemSearch, 
im using _.lodash/underscore

```
{
"tileRecords"   : [
{   
"tileName"      :   "Fama Brown",   
"tileGroup"     :   ["Polished", "Matt", "Rought"],
"tileDetails"   :   
        {
        "tileSize"          :   "60x60",
        "tileType"          :   "Polished"
        }
},
{   
"tileName"      :   "Fama Nero",    
"tileGroup"     :   ["Polished", "Matt", "Rought"],
"tileDetails"   :   
        {
        "tileSize"          :   "60x60",
        "tileType"          :   "Polished"
        }
},
{   
"tileName"      :   "Dolce Beige",  
"tileGroup"     :   ["Italian", "Matt", "Rought"],
"tileDetails"   :   
        {
        "tileSize"          :   "60x60",
        "tileType"          :   "Polished"
        }
}
] 
}
```

How can i get the object tileName : Fama Brown and Fama Nero using a filter at tileGroup with value of "Polished"?

Since that group has the only value of Polished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) instead of lodash which is very straight forward to implement,
If you are using it with ng-repeat, try below,

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in tiles.tileRecords | pick: tileGroupFilter">
  {{ tile.tileName }}
</div>
```

And in your controller

```
    $scope.tiles = {
                       "tileRecords"   : [
                          {   
                             "tileName"      :   "Fama Brown",   
                             "tileGroup"     :   ["Polished", "Matt", "Rought"],
                             "tileDetails"   :   
                                 {
                                     "tileSize"          :   "60x60",
                                     "tileType"          :   "Polished"
                                 }
                           },
                           {   
                              "tileName"      :   "Fama Nero",    
                              "tileGroup"     :   ["Polished", "Matt", "Rought"],
                              "tileDetails"   :   
                                  {
                                      "tileSize"          :   "60x60",
                                      "tileType"          :   "Polished"
                                   }
                            },
                            {   
                                "tileName"      :   "Dolce Beige",  
                                "tileGroup"     :   ["Italian", "Matt", "Rought"],
                                "tileDetails"   :   
                                    {
                                        "tileSize"          :   "60x60",
                                        "tileType"          :   "Polished"
                                    }
                             }
                        ] 
                   };


$scope.tileGroupFilter = function(elm) {
  return (elem.tileGroup.indexOf("Polished") > 0) ;
}
```

Comment: what is pick: in filter? and how its work? sory for here still new in angular